# Yii2 Gridview display custom content instead of filter fields

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

How can I display custom content in the area shown in the image?

[Screenshot of my Gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUER7.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `filter` in your column config. Because we don't have additional information about your columns / grid code a simple example.
Please add next time some code fragment  to your question.

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ....
        'room',
        [
           'attribute'=>'room_no',
           'filter'=>'whatever',
        ],
        ...
     ]
   ]);
```